# CSS: Get "disabled" input background color?

Tags: css

Is there a special CSS system color equivalent to the system's disabled text input background color?  I know there's one for the disabled *text* color (`GrayText`), but I can't find one for the *background* color.

To make it more clear, I'm looking for the background color that gets set when you do something like:

```
<input type="text" disabled />
```

I don't want to restyle disabled inputs; I want to use the existing system style elsewhere.

**Edit:**

To be even more clear, I'm looking for the **system color keyword**, not the actual color.  For example, to use the system's defined disabled *text* color, you would do this:

```
<span style="color: GrayText;">This text looks like disabled text in your operating system</span>
```

I just can't find the one for the *background* color.

Comment: are you saying you want to know the specific hex color of that background?

Comment: What about using Firebug (http://getfirebug.com/) or Chrome Inspector to figure it out?

Comment: No, I want the system color *name* used in CSS (if there is one).  See [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/ui.html#system-colors) for the ones I looked through.  I'm wanting to know if I've overlooked it, or if it's a later addition, or just doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the latest CSS spec, there is no system color keyword for "disabled" background color.

Answer (score 3):

I encountered this issue while trying to style a javascript replacement for a select. While there has been no progress in the CSS spec, there is a jQuery alternative.

```
$("input:disabled").css("background-color")
```

This returns a RGB color from an already disabled input, so unfortunately it's not as flexible as a CSS color, but it will work across browsers and reacts to custom colors applied to disabled elements through CSS.

Comment: This seems to be the best solution now. Even if you don't have such disabled input, you can create one (`$('<input disabled>')`), append to the body (so the CSS is evaulated), read the value and detach. Maybe also set display to `none` before appending to avoid blinking, but I'm not sure if every browser will set background-color if it's not visible.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't the purpose of the keyword - the use of colour [I believe] is technically up to the browser vendor - if they observe the OS preferences then thats up to them.

There are a small number of color names originally [in the W3C spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-color/#colorunits). However these were extended to include the list of [X11 color names](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X11_color_names) that were supported by most browser vendors.

Together those lists are all the *valid* names acceptable in a browser.